# Convert Optional(Set(["6", "14"])) to [String]

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I am having trouble trying to convert a `Set` to a `[String]`. I am using the Eureka form and getting my values as:

```
let values = form.values()
```

which is a `[String:Any]`.

My field is:

```
values["field_name"]
```

If I use the following, I get nil:

```
var incidents : [String]?

if let incidentRow = values["field_name"]! {
    incidents = incidentRow as? [String]
}
```

Comment: It seems odd you would use `if let` and a forced-unwrap on the same line. What is the actual value of `incidentRow`?

Comment: What exactly do you need an Array for? Creating an Array from a Set won't "bring back" the ordering.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I needed the Array to send to a server. I would not need the ordering, just the selected values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have a Set, as the output `Optional(Set(["6", "14"]))` suggests, then it is not an Array (which is what `[String]`) is. Your test `as? [String]` is thus doomed to failure, and so you get `nil`. You cannot *cast* (using `as`) a thing of one type to a different type that it is not.

Instead, you must *coerce* from Set to Array. Do it like this:

```
if let theSet = values["field_name"] as? Set<String> {
    incidents = Array(theSet)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Optional.map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map):

```
let incidents = values["field_name"].map(Array.init)
```